# Is there a way to step through Rust code with the asm it compiled to in vscode?

Tags: debugging, assembly, visual-studio-code, rust, arm64

Decades ago I learned a lot about C, C++, and assembly by looking at the compiled code in the debugger interleaved with the assembly.

I'm now learning Rust on a new M1 Mac and want to do the same thing. I especially want to learn about how well the zero-cost abstractions work. But I'm not proficient at Rust or ARM assembly.

I'm using VSCode and I can't find any way to see the Rust and assembly interleaved like I used to back in the day on my Amiga and 486 PC.

By Googling I can find ways to get `rustc` to generate the asm, but it's without the Rust code and very hard to follow, especially in an asm dialect I don't yet know.

I know I can see Rust and the asm it compiles to side-by-side on Godbolt, and that's great. But I want to see the code for my whole app and step through it. Is that possible these days?

Comment: By the way, I do realize that the optimizer can radically rearrange the asm compared to the high-level language. That was also the case back in the day and was just a limitation we were aware of, it didn't outright prevent interleaved asm.

Comment: I just discovered after posting this that VSCode has LLDB: Toggle Disassembly and LLDB: Show Disassembly commands. This is helpful and shows where execution is currently at, and just the current function, but it's not interleaved.

Comment: Apparently you can have the Rust on one side and asm on the other in a split view. But they're not aligned and only the asm side is stepped through. The asm does have comments saying which line of Rust they relate to though, which makes it seem like this should be very possible.

Comment: Modern compilers are probably more aggressive than they were in your 486 days, or especially amiga.  As often as not, interleaving source and asm would be *more* confusing, not less, as execution appeared to bounce around between source lines.  (So the same source line might have to get repeated.)  Although you can do that with some static tools, like GNU Binutils `objdump -d` has an  option for that.  I assume `llvm-objdump` (probably installed as objdump on MacOS) has a similar option.

Comment: If you want to see how the source lines up with asm, though, I highly recommend https://godbolt.org/.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) explains how to use it (with C / C++ examples, but writing funcs that take args and return a value works the same in Rust as a way to get the compiler to do something without optimizing away constants. I.e. to make asm that's interesting to look at.)